# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^{r+1}\frac{\cos(2r-1)x}{2r-1}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation, solution-verification

I would like to know how to evaluate $$\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^{r+1}\frac{\cos(2r-1)x}{2r-1}$$

There are a couple of issues I have with this. Firstly, depending on the value of $x$, it seems, at least numerically, that this value is always
$$\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}}$$
If this is true, how would I prove this?

Secondly, I tried using complex numbers to evalaute this, as shown briefly below:

$$C=\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^{r+1}\frac{\cos(2r-1)x}{2r-1}$$
$$S=\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^{r+1}\frac{\sin(2r-1)x}{2r-1}$$
$$\implies C+iS=\arctan e^{ix}$$
on using the power series of $\arctan x$. Differentiating yields a *completely imaginary number*:
$$\frac{i}{2}\sec x$$
which proves that the value of $C$ is a constant. However, this gives me no information whatsoever on the value of $C$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would you want the exact value of this series? Or are you only interested in some "properties" of this series?

Comment: @mrsamy I'm just looking at it out of curiosity.

Comment: That's a fair reason :-)

Comment: Have you studied some Fourier Series, perhaps in advanced analysis...or harmonic analysis...or stuff?

Comment: @DonAntonio unfortunately not; I am still in high school and don't know a lot beyond the high school curriculum.

Comment: @A-Level Student: what a coincidence. I am also calculating this series $C=\cos(x)-\dfrac{1}{3}\cos(3x)+\dfrac{1}{3}\cos(5x)...$. The sine series is just exactly the same. I got your answer. In the book "The analytic theory of heat" of Fourier, chapter III, he wrote that the sum of this series is $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. It is an equation he used over and over.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Could you tell me why your line of reasoning is that $C$ is a constant?

Comment: @JamesWarthington cool, that's an interesting coincidence :) I have written extremely brief working above, I don't blame you for wondering about that. Recall a couple of facts: differentiating something completely real yields a completely real derivative, and differentiating something completely imaginary yields a completely imaginary derivative. In our case, we find that $\frac{d}{dx}(C+iS)=\frac{d}{dx}\arctan (e^{ix})$ is *completely* imaginary. This means that either $C+iS$ is completely imaginary or $C$ is a constant, as when constant are differentiated they 'disappear'...

Comment: @JamesWarthington (continued) .... As we know that $C+iS$ *isn't* completely imaginary we conclude that $C$ must be a constant.

Comment: @JamesWarthington btw note that the value of $C$ can also be $-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @So why did we choose $\pi/4$? $C$ could take 2 values, which mean it is divergent series, is it not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120235/discussion-between-a-level-student-and-james-warthington).

Comment: @A-LevelStudent BTW, I have written on the method $C+iS$ for "summing" certain kinds of trigonometric series on my blog, I credit you for being the first to introduce it to me: https://analysisbeauty.blogspot.com/2021/02/blog-post_30.html

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Also, for your interest $\sin(x)-\dfrac{1}{2}\sin(2x)+\dfrac{1}{3}\sin(3x)...=\dfrac{x}{2}$. This is drawn from a paper of Euler. He arrived at this result by integrating a string of other series. This is an important series since you see it a lot in Fourier's book.

Comment: @JamesWarthington you may be interested in my new answer to this question.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I got your answer. I will have a close look tomorrow. Thanks! It's good to see you progress when learning Math :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, the real part of the sum, $C$, is constant no matter what the value of $x$ (so long as $x$ is real). Thus plug in $x = 0$

$$C = \operatorname{Re}(\arctan e^{i0}) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! However, it seems that $C$ can take different values; namely $$\pm\frac{\pi}{4}$$ at least according to desmos. How do I obtain the negative value?

Comment: *... no matter what the value of $x$...* - not quite (replace $x$ by $x+\pi$ in the original series to see what actually happens). And... *actually* we reinvent [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_wave)... or more specifically [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave).

Comment: @metamorphy I see, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @A-LevelStudent the sum changes values at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ because arctan is undefined at $i$. It's like what happens with the graph of $\arctan(2\tan x)$ at the same points. But thanks for pointing it out, I would not have caught that otherwise.

Comment: Why isn't $\arctan$ defined at $i$? Isn't it just equal to $i~\text{artanh}1$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent there are two ways of looking at it. The derivative of $\arctan x$ is $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ which has poles at $x=\pm i$. The second is see what happens when you try to solve $$\tan z = i$$ with Euler's formula. Also in the formula you have, $\tanh^{-1}1$ is infinity.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I must be tired to have missed that :) Thanks once again!

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: what is $\tanh^{-1}(1)$?

Comment: @robjohn it's $\infty$; I forgot that yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

**The Series**

This series only converges for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If $x\not\in\mathbb{R}$, the terms do not go to $0$.$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^{r+1}\frac{\cos((2r-1)x)}{2r-1}\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^{r+1}\frac{e^{i(2r-1)x}}{2r-1}+\frac12\sum_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^{r+1}\frac{e^{-i(2r-1)x}}{2r-1}\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac12\tan^{-1}\left(e^{ix}\right)+\frac12\tan^{-1}\left(e^{-ix}\right)\tag{1c}\\[9pt]
&=\Re\left(\tan^{-1}\left(e^{ix}\right)\right)\tag{1d}\\[12pt]
&=\frac\pi4\,\sgn(\cos(x))\tag{1e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1b)}$: $\cos(x)=\frac12\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)$
$\text{(1c)}$: power series for $\tan^{-1}(z)$
$\text{(1d)}$: $\tan(\bar z)=\overline{\tan(z)}$
$\text{(1e)}$: $|\tan(z)\,|=1$ when $\Re(z)=\pm\frac\pi4$
$\phantom{\text{(1e):}}$ and $\Re(\tan(z))$ has the same sign as $\Re(z)$
$\phantom{\text{(1e):}}$ also, if $\cos(x)=0$, all the terms of the series are $0$

---

**Concerning $\boldsymbol{\tan(x+iy)}$**

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(x+iy)&=\frac{\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)}{\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i\sin(x)\sinh(y)}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)+i\sinh(y)\cosh(y)}{\cos^2(x)\cosh^2(y)+\sin^2(x)\sinh^2(y)}\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
is on the unit circle when the absolute values of the numerator and denominator are equal. Since $\cosh^2(y)-\sinh^2(y)=1$, equation $\text{(2a)}$ says that is when
$$
\begin{align}
\sin^2(x)\cosh^2(y)+\cos^2(x)\sinh^2(y)&=\cos^2(x)\cosh^2(y)+\sin^2(x)\sinh^2(y)\tag{3a}\\[6pt]
\sin^2(x)&=\cos^2(x)\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $|\tan(z)\,|=1$ when $\Re(z)=\pm\frac\pi4$

Furthermore, equation $\text{(2b)}$ says not only that $\tan(\bar z)=\overline{\tan(z)}$, but also that, when $\Re(z)=\pm\frac\pi4$, $\Re(\tan(z))$ has the same sign as $\Re(z)$.

[image]

Comment: This answer has finally explained to me why $\tan (\bar {z})=\overline{\tan(z)}$. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually $f(\bar z)=\overline{f(z)}$ is true for any function that is analytic on a connected region that includes a real interval and is real-valued on that real interval.  See [property of a holomorphic function on a connected open subset of complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930060).

Answer (score 1):

I've learned some new related facts since posting the question, one of which solves this very simply. The relevant formula, stated below, can be found by using the fact $\arctan z=-i\operatorname{artanh} iz$. $$\arctan(x+iy)=\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{2x}{1-x^2-y^2}+\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{artanh}\frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2}$$
Plugging in $x=\cos x$ and $y=\sin x$ we find that
$$\arctan e^{ix}=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(\pm\infty)+\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{artanh}\sin x$$
And thus $$C=\pm\frac{\pi}{4}$$